# Using RedirectToAction with custom type parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

asp.net mvc 2

I have this action in Identity controller

```
public ActionResult Details(string id, MessageUi message)
{
```

And I'm trying to redirect to this action from another controller, but I don't know how should I pass the message parameter

I was trying with

```
    var id = "someidvalue"
    var message = new MessageUi("somevalue");
    return RedirectToAction("Details", "Identity", new { id, message});
}
```

but message parameter is null

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's normal. You cannot pass complex objects in urls when redirecting and that's the reason why the `MessageUi` object is not received. Only scalar properties which will be translated into `&`-separated key/value pairs in the url.

---

One possibility would be to pass all the simple properties of this object so that the default model binder can reconstruct it at the target location:

```
var id = "someidvalue"
var message = new MessageUi("somevalue");
return RedirectToAction("Details", "Identity", new { 
    id = id, 
    MessageProp1 = message.MessageProp1,
    MessageProp2 = message.MessageProp2,
    MessageProp3 = message.MessageProp3,
});
```

---

You could also pass only a message id:

```
var id = "someidvalue";
return RedirectToAction("Details", "Identity", new { 
    id = id, 
    messageId = "somevalue"
});
```

and have the message object being reconstructed in the details action using this id:

```
public ActionResult Details(string id, string messageId)
{
    var message = new MessageUi(messageId);
    ...
}
```

and this job could be greatly done by a custom model binder for the `MessageUi` type.

---

Another possibility would be to use `TempData` or `Session`:

```
var id = "someidvalue";
TempData["message"] = new MessageUi("somevalue");
return RedirectToAction("Details", "Identity", new { id });
```

and then inside the Details action:

```
var message = TempData["message"] as MessageUi;
```